# How to understand a React file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-redux, react-laravel

I am using React in Laravel and I found a problem that I can't refresh or reload a page in React. So to solve this problem I found many suggestions like use `historyApiFallback`, `404 page` and many other ways But I found none of them useful to me now.

I know I can't do this because React has no system for it because of **server- and client-side routing**. Then i found a demo project where they used Redux and I can refresh their page. I got the demo project where i can use any component and refresh them how many times I want. So there is a file name with **Base.js** and I am not understanding this file why he used it what is doing. Let me share the file and where it was used.

**Base.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './components/Header';

const Base = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <main>{children}</main>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.Auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Base);
```

**Header.Js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import * as actions from '../store/actions';

class Header extends Component {
  handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(actions.authLogout());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h1 className="logo my-0 font-weight-normal h4">
          <Link to="/">Laravel React</Link>
        </h1>

        {this.props.isAuthenticated && (
          <div className="navigation d-flex justify-content-end">
            <Nav>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/archive">
                  Archive
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/Myfile">
                Myfile
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                  Account
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>Settings</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem onClick={this.handleLogout}>
                    Log Out
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.Auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

**Public.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Base from '../Base';

const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (
      <Base>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Base>
    )}
  />
);

PublicRoute.propTypes = {};

export default PublicRoute;
```

**split.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Base from '../Base';

const SplitRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  fallback: Fallback,
  isAuthenticated,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (isAuthenticated ? (
      <Base>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Base>
    ) : (
      <Base>
        < Fallback {...props} />
      </Base>
    ))}
  />
);

SplitRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.Auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SplitRoute);
```

Now it has authenticated system so I understand it but why it is using **base function** and what it is doing? I am not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like is that the Base.js is a container for the Header and any rendered children (passed props). This is a good practise in react to separate logic and make it more readable. So when he imports Base into the Public.js file, it will render the Header and the component he is passing to it from the public function props.

Think of it like the skeleton of the layout, by importing Base it will always render the header and any logic inside of the header file, and whatever he is passing down to it. As you can see he is passing different components to it depending on whether isAuthenticated is true or false. If it is false, they are rendering Base and passing a fallback component - this will render inside of the main tag within the Base function.